# Kubernetes Installation with Vagrant & CoreOS and insecure Docker registry

Tags: vagrant, kubernetes, coreos

I have followed the steps at https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/kubernetes-on-vagrant.html to launch a multi-node Kubernetes cluster using Vagrant and CoreOS.

But,I could not find a way to set an insecure docker registry for that environment. 
To be more specific, when I run

```
kubectl run api4docker --image=myhost:5000/api4docker:latest --replicas=2 --port=8080
```

on this set up, it tries to get the image thinking it is a secure registry. But, it is an insecure one.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Hi @turgos, I'm not sure who you are referring to by "it" in "it tries to get the image thinking it is a secure registry". Anyway, if you log into the node, and run `docker pull`, does it work?

Comment: Hi @caesarxuchao. No, it does not work when I login to one of the worker nodes and run docker pull. When I say "it", I mean docker on the kubernetes workers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved the issue for now. I will add later if I can automate it on Vagrantfile.

```
cd ./coreos-kubernetes/multi-node/vagrant
```

`vagrant ssh w1` (and repeat these steps for w2, w3, etc.)

```
cd /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d

sudo vi 50-insecure-registry.conf
```

add below line to this file

```
[Service]
Environment=DOCKER_OPTS='--insecure-registry="<your-registry-host>/24"'
```

after adding this file, we need to restart the docker service on this worker.

```
sudo systemctl stop docker
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start docker
sudo systemctl status docker
```

now, docker pull should work on this worker.

```
docker pull <your-registry-host>:5000/api4docker
```

Let's try to deploy our application on Kubernetes cluster one more time.

Logout from the workers and come back to your host.

```
$ kubectl run api4docker --image=<your-registry-host>:5000/api4docker:latest --replicas=2 --port=8080 —env="SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=production"
```

when you get the pods, you should see the status running.

```
$ kubectl get pods

NAME                          READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
api4docker-2839975483-9muv5   1/1       Running   0          8s
api4docker-2839975483-lbiny   1/1       Running   0          8s
```